# Extracting required Variables from Event Log file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, text-parsing, string-parsing, text-extraction

[image]

sample first row of event log file ,here i have successfully extracted evrything apart from last key value pair which is attribute-

```
{"event_type":"ActionClicked","event_timestamp":1451583172592,"arrival_timestamp":1451608731845,"event_version":"3.0",
  "application":{"app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:
    4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","package_name":"com.think.vito","sdk":{"name":"aws-sdk-android","version":"2.2.2"}
    ,"title":"Vito","version_name":"1.0.2.1","version_code":"3"},"client":{"client_id":"438b152e-5b7c-4e99-9216-831fc15b0c07",
      "cognito_id":"us-east-1:448efb89-f382-4975-a1a1-dd8a79e1dd0c"},"device":{"locale":{"code":"en_GB","country":"GB",
        "language":"en"},"make":"samsung","model":"GT-S5312","platform":{"name":"ANDROID","version":"4.1.2"}},
  "session":{"session_id":"c15b0c07-20151231-173052586","start_timestamp":1451583052586},"attributes":{"OfferID":"20186",
    "Category":"40000","CustomerID":"304"},"metrics":{}}
```

Hello Every One ,I am trying to extract the content from Event log file  as shown in attached image .As to requirement i have to fetch `customer ID`, `offer id`, `category` these are important variable i need to extract from the this event log file .this is csv formatted file. i tryed with regular expression but it is't working because you can observe format of every column is different. As you see first row has `category` `customer id` `offer id` and second row is totally blank in this case regular expression wont work apart from this we have to consider we have to consider all possible condition, we has 14000 sample.in Event log file ...#Jason # Parsing #Python #Pandas

Comment: Is this a plain text file? Does every line start and end with `{}`? If so, seems like you can read the file line by line and use `literal_eval` to turn each line to a Python `dict` object.

Comment: Can you provide the actual piece of your data log instead of the image format? You don't expect us to type your data one by one, right?

Comment: yes , it was in txt format earlier.it was huge file i extracted below variable from event log file event_type
event_timestamp
arrival_timestamp
event_version
application { 
  app_id
  cognito_identity_pool_id
  }
client{}
device{}
session{}
attributes{}

Comment: Why do you have single quotes in the image but double quotes in the text? (The latter could be in JSON format.)

Comment: @ayhan image file is in csv format and where as the in text form its in .txt format ...after extracting from .txt file i separated every key to individual csv file .

Comment: can i just extract only the value related to one key , and create a column for that key only ,but the problem here is some rows might have that key and some rows may not have ...in that case its difficult ..@DeepSpace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient way to convert nested json records in a text file (delimited by line) to DataFrame object, but it kinda does the job.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('path_to_your_text_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: eval(json_normalize(json.loads(x.rstrip())).to_json(orient="records")[1:-1]), data)
e = pd.DataFrame(data)
print e.head()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

The data, after your edit, now appears to be JSON data. You can still use `literal_eval` as below, or you could use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module:

```
import json

with open('event.log') as events:
    for line in events:
        event = json.loads(line)
        # process event dictionary
```

To access the `CustomerID`, `OfferID`, `Category` etc. you need to access the nested dictionary associated with the key `'attributes'` in the `event` dictionary:

```
print(event['attributes']['CustomerID'])
print(event['attributes']['OfferID'])
print(event['attributes']['Category'])
```

If it is the case that some keys could be missing use `dict.get()` instead:

```
print(event['attributes'].get('CustomerID'))
print(event['attributes'].get('OfferID'))
print(event['attributes'].get('Category'))
```

Now you will get `None` if the key is missing.

You can extend this principle to access other items with the dictionary.

If I understand your question you also want to create a CSV file containing the extracted fields. You use the extracted values with `csv.DictWriter` like this:

```
import csv

with open('event.log') as events, open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fields = ['CustomerID', 'OfferID', 'Category']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in events:
        event = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(event['attributes'])
```

`DictWriter` will simply leave fields empty when the dictionary is missing keys.

---

**Original answer**
The data is not in CSV format, it appears to contain Python dictionary strings. These can be parsed into Python dictionaries using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('event.log') as events:
    for line in events:
        event = literal_eval(line)
        # process event dictionary
```

Comment: we require to extract the values of customer id  and offer id and category and also in some rows "{ }" with no key : value pair in it                   Sir , the Result was                                                                         >>> event 
{u'MenuItem': u'Category', u'CustomerID': u'364'} @mhawke

Comment: @NabiShaikh: Once you have the dictionary you can access the attributes in it. Looking at your updated sample of data (which now looks to be JSON data!) you actually have nested dictionaries, so you would access the customer id with `event['attributes']['CustomerID']` for example.

Comment: ,The EVENT LOG file is in .txt format , its not jason format i am facing error                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: u'Lat', u'Long'

Comment: @NabiShaikh: it is a text file, but the contents are JSON. The `json` parser successfully parses it, doesn't it? Don't pass dictionaries to `DictWriter.writerow()` that contain keys that you have not defined in the `fieldnames` argument to `DictWriter`. In this case `Lat` and `Long` are being passed to `writerow()`. Don't do that.